# How Json-ld with Hydra works in Apache jena in JAVA?

Tags: java, api, jena, apache-jena, hydra-core

**Note: I am replacing http:// with http:/ in my Question because I haven't enough reputation to post link more than two times in my question.**

I am explaining my problem step by step .To view exactly put the URL whatever I will tell in this console http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/console/

Step 1) Put this URL http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/event-api/ .This my EntryPoint.

Step 2) Select "events" (an EntryPoint) and apply get to retrieves all Event entities by clicking on "events" value.Hydra related stuff like Supported Operation on this is defined in vocab.

Step 3) You will now moved to this link http:/www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/event-api/events/ .This link contains EventCollection and have lots of members of Event Entity type.

Step 4) Select a member from list of members.Click to get an Event Entity and now you will moved to new URL of an Event Entity like this URL(link) http:/www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/event-api/events/59.

Now you get familiar with flow from an EntryPoint to an Event Entity.


So my question is how can I write this flow in Java with Apache jena library?

I want to check what are the Supported Operation I can perform on an value of Object in triple in Model

 So , Have I to check both Supported Operation through Type(http:/www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type) of Object value(eg.http:/www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/event-api/events/59) and predicate (http:/www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#member) ?